# Ubuntu 18.04 Extend Disk

Tags: ubuntu, partition, vmware, resize2fs, cfdisk

I've got a virtual Ubuntu 18.04 server which is running low on disk space. As this is a virtual server I increased the hard disk size in vSphere. I can see the free space in cfdisk but am unsure how to expand the filesystem partition to take advantage of the new space. I can see there is a resize option for the partition but I'm unclear on whether or not that will also format the partitions and lose my data... Bit of a linux n00b, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**cfdisk** output:

```
Device         Start        End       Sectors    Size  Type

/dev/sda1       2048       4095          2048      1M  BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096   41940991      41936896     20G  Linux filesystem
Free space  41940992  104857566      62916575     30G
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For the n00b: Connect with X forwarding enabled (`ssh -X yourserver`), install `gparted` and use the user-friendly GUI to resize `/dev/sda2`.

A more advanced user would probably fire up `parted /dev/sda`, then enter `resizepart 2`. The end of the partition will automatically be selected to match the end of the disk. This will only resize the partition, though. The file-system can be resized to span the whole partition with the appropriate tool, like `resize2fs /dev/sda2` for ext2/3/4.

Answer (score 0):

As an **additional** note: 
In this case (free space after the end of the partition which will be resized) it should be possible to resize the partition by:

```
growpart /dev/sda 2
```

You can install [`growpart`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/growpart.1.html) by installing the package: [`cloud-guest-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cloud-guest-utils).

Just as a note: 
There is always a risk of losing data when performing this kind of operations on disks/partitions.

Comment: Good point. Yet I want to add that data-loss during online growing is so very unlikely, I consider it safe.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeking to do the same as the OP. My only difference is that I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server.

I had not tried `cfdisk` yet to see such info (I tried `df` and `lsblk`), so I went ahead and ran `cfdisk`.

I was surprised that `cfdisk` itself had an option to [Resize] my disk right there. No need to use other tools, I just went and navigated to my sda, and selected the [Resize] Option. Including a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Of course now one has to resize the actual filesystem, etc.. I didn't recall exactly how to do it, but I did remember that I wrote an answer here a month ago where I summed up such steps (sharing it in case it helps someone else) https://askubuntu.com/a/1393329/658154

Basically resize the Physical Volume (`pvresize`), and then resize the Logical Volume (`lvextend`) to finally resize the filesystem (`resize2fs`).

Comment: If you use `lvresize -r -l 100%FREE /dev/mapper/...` after the `pvresize` the file system will be extended without any further commands.

Comment: @doneal24 thanks for the tip :) will try it next time I have to resize a machine

Comment: If you do it right you can resize the disk in vSphere and expand the lv from the command line with no downtime. Very useful for production servers.

Comment: @doneal24 I have ESXI, but not the vSphere suite (yet?). I've heard that vSphere is quite useful, and your comment confirmed that to me. Thus why I have to do it more manually: edit the machine, expand the vdisk, and then the steps mentioned inside the machine... Thanks for that observation, as it makes me realize vSphere is something we should get :)